# JSTL attributes persisting through tiles/jsp:include

Tags: jsp, jstl, tiles

I am currently using JSTL and Tiles (though i'm pretty sure this problem is not tiles issue) for a web application.

I would like to, at the template level include a "setVars" file that is a simple file that include a slew of JSTL variables

e.g.

testPageVars.jsp

```
<c:set var="currentPage" value="testPage" scope="request" />
<c:set var="forward" value="newPage" scope="request" />
...
<c:set var="test" value="true" scope="request" />
```

this would be included somewhere on the main layout. However it seems as though these dont persist through a  or a  or a

It seems as though they dont get "compiled" (not sure if thats the correct word)

so in my mainLayout.jsp

```
<jsp:include page="testPageVars.jsp"/>
<c:if test="${test == 'true'}>
   TEST WORKED
</c:if>
```

does not function.

**Any thoughts on how to get my desired effect?** Currently the only solution I have come up with is moving those values into the Java (I'm using struts) and have them set there. Which doesn't scale as well as I would like.

**EDIT**

tiles-def.xml

```
<definition name="main.layout" path="/jsp/mainLayout.jsp">
        <put name="actionVars" value="/jsp/testVars.jsp"/>
    </definition>
```

mainLayout.jsp

```
    <tiles:insert attribute="actionVars"/>
    <c:if test="${test == 'true'}">
       TRUE TWICE
    </c:if>
```

testVars.jsp

```
<c:set var="test" value="true" scope="request"/>
<c:if test="${test == 'true'}">
    TRUE
</c:if>
```

Comment: Can you share full code for both JSPs

Comment: This is the test case i am using. I want the output to be 
TRUE
TRUE TWICE

Comment: well i am stupid, i didn't include the tag libs on the var file.

Comment: :) been there. It happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add the tag libs on the var file.